# Search either misses some questions or they are incorrectly sorted in the active and newest tabs

Tags: bug, search, last-activity

On some sites, several searches that I tried after after choosing active tab or newest tab, the search only show questions at least 2 days old.

If I search for some extremely common word - for example limit on Mathematics site - at the top of the [active tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=limit) and the [newest tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=limit) questions with last activity/creation day at least two days ago are shown.

Below are screenshots from Mathematics. I have noticed the same behavior on several other sites. (Although on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=limit) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=limit) the search worked as expected - some relatively new questions were shown among the results.)

This is what I get in the active tab.

[image: screenshot]

And this is the newest tab.

[image: screenshot]

Browsing among questions tagged limits you can see many question that should have been displayed in the [newest tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits?sort=newest) and [active tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits?sort=active) of the above searches (and are newer than 2 days).

Comment: Thanks to gnat for noticing that this is a duplicate - the problem has already been reported. (I am leaving the question here rather than deleting it - perhaps there is some additional value in having screenshots.)